# Update column values in plsql anonymous block

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I tried to update a new column in my table 'EMP' which are created with null values.  the three columns are `deptno`,`sal`,`levl`

I created a plsql block to update those column values as following :

```
declare
  cursor c is select dept_no,sal,levl from emp;
  v_dept_no number;
  v_sal number;
  v_levl number;
  v_comm number;
  v_update varchar2(1000);
begin
  open c;

  loop
    fetch c into v_dept_no,v_sal,v_levl;
    exit when c% notfound;
    v_update:='update emp
      set dept_no='||:dept_no||','||'sal='||:sal||','||'levl='||:level||' '||
      'where emp_no='||:emp_no;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_dept_no||':'||'|'||v_sal||':'||'|'||'comm: '||v_comm);

  close c;
end;
/
```

But my code keep giving me an error : "Error report -Missing defines"

I need  to create case statement in that block to update the values as the requirement needs but I don't have idea where I must create it !

The output must be as the dbms statement that I write

```
dbms_output.put_line(v_dept_no||':'||'|'||v_sal||':'||'|'||'comm: '||v_comm);
```

The requirement is : create three new columns and create code to update them through a case statement based on the salary  X dynamic inserted commission.

like :

```
dept_no:10|sal:110|comm:0.01
dept_no:20|sal:500|comm:0.0
levl:3|sal:1000
else sal:100|comm:0.05
```

The values must be dynamic,

Comment: What that poring website.. there is no body help :P

Comment: Answers on StackOverflow come from *volunteers*.  You have no SLA with us and you are not entitled to an immediate response.

Comment: I fail to see why you need dynamic SQL here. And why are you using a cursor (aka "slow-by-slow") approach in the first place. As far as I can tell your PL/SQL block is a very complicated way to obfuscate a simple statement like `update  emp set dept_no = :dept_no, sale = :sal, levl = :level where emp_no = :emp_no`? And why do you only print the _last_ row from the cursor?

Comment: Please clarify your question properly so that you will geta good response.

Comment: As per the question i dont see a point of using complicated PLSQL. As @a_horse_with_no_name stated correctly in the comment

Comment: It seem the error comes from elsewhere. not from running this piece of code.